# Add SVM to last layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, svm

**What I did:**

I implement the following model using of Keras:

```
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=np.random.seed(7), shuffle=True)

train_X = np.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = np.reshape(test_X, (test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))

inp = Input((train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))
lstm = LSTM(1, return_sequences=False)(inp)
output = Dense(train_Y.shape[1], activation='softmax')(lstm)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_split=.20, epochs=2, batch_size=50)
```

**What I want:**

I want to add SVM to the last layer in my model but i dont know how? Any idea?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal Can you give me an example? I dont know how do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for adding svm as last layer.

```
inp = Input((train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))
lstm = LSTM(1, return_sequences=False)(inp)
output = Dense(train_Y.shape[1], activation='softmax', W_regularizer=l2(0.01)))(lstm)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='hinge', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_split=.20, epochs=2, batch_size=50)
```

Here I have used `hinge` as loss considering binary categorised target. But if it is more than that, then you can consider using `categorical_hinge`

Answer (score 4):

Change `softmax` to `linear` and add `kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4)` instead `W_regularizer=l2(0.01)` using keras 2.2.4. Use `loss = categorical_hinge`.